# How to store editable copies of original data in a relational database?

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database

Let's assume I have two entities: **Company** and **Order**.

**Company:**

```
Id
Name
Phone
```

**Order:**

```
Id
CompanyId
Name
TotalAmount
```

I simplified these entities, in the real project they are much more bigger.

In my application, I have a Companies view, where I can do basic CRUD operations. The same is for Orders.

When I create an order I must choose the company from my database. The problem is that I must allow the user to **modify** company data for each order, so it **can be modified only for particular order**.

I have 2 solutions:

**First solution:**
Create a separate table OrderCompany where I can store copies of Companies data for each order. In this case, I can edit the copy and it will not affect the original company, but I have doubts because it will be a full copy of the Contacts table with only one additional field - OrderId.

**Second solution:**
Store copies of companies directly inside the Companies table and add OrderId in this table. Original companies will be stored with OrderId = null, for copies OrderId will be assigned. In this case, I don't have 2 almost identical tables like in the first solution, but I'm not sure that storing originals and copies in the same table is a good idea.

Which of these two solutions is better in your opinion? Maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are confusing some different concepts.  A "company" should not be changing.  However, companies might have something -- say "contacts" -- that do change.

So, I think you want a model where you have:

- `companies`, which has basic information about companies, such as `companyid` and company name and so on.  This information does not change (or at least not *per order*).  A company would also have a default "contact".
- `companyContacts`, which would be for a contact in a company.  This would have a `companyId` and then additional information.  Different contacts might be used for different orders.
- `orders` which would have a `companyContactId`.

Then the order would be assigned to a company and to a particular contact within the company.  New contact information can be created as necessary,.

Comment: In our case, there are no Contacts, only Companies. Company data can be adjusted for each Order. For example, I have a company Microsoft, and I want to create 3 Orders for this company, but in one particular order, I want to change the company phone. This is not a common case in our system, but it still exists.

Comment: @GlebSkripnikov . . . My suggestion is that your data model is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose we can go with your 1st approach as any change in the company table will not cost any changes in  OrderCompany table.